# Incorrect Totals for measure when blanks present in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a selector slicer `TYPE` (based on sum of quantity or sum of sales).

If `Sales or None` is selected, `TYPE=sum(FactSales[Sales])` is calculated and if `Quantity` then `TYPE=sum(FactSales[Quantity])`.

There is another measure for Same Period Last Year using

```
TYPE LY = SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DimDate[DateFormat].[Date])`
```

Next measure is difference between this year and last year as

```
variance = IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Type])),NOT(ISBLANK([Type LY]))),CALCULATE([Type]-[Type LY]),BLANK())
```

There are some customer whose this year or last year sales may be blank or 0. the table shows correct value but the total is wrong because it add up even for blanks:

[image: screenshot]

I have been stuck on this issue for a while now, this wrong total shows wrong value in multi-row card for each customer. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that output, you need to iterate over the `Year` values, and only calculate the sum for years where neither `Type` nor `Type LY` are blank:

```
Annual Variance = 
    SUMX ( 
        VALUES ( DimDate[Year] ),
        IF ( 
            NOT ( ISBLANK( [Type] ) ) && NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Type LY] ) ),
            [Type] - [Type LY],
            BLANK()
        )
    )
```

Comment: This helped, I just had to filter Type LY as blank, if Type this year is blank.

Comment: I'm also facing a similar situation where I have used SELECTEDVALUE() within IF()
and it returns BLANK() as the default

It causes an incorrect Grand Total value. (Seems like filtered values also added)

What would be the best option to handle this situation?
cast BLANK() into 0 ?